# Clearing a singly linked list

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, erase

I can not figure out where my problem is but I am not able to clear this singly linked list.  I have tried about everything I can think of.  I am testing it with a list with one element (well actually a hash table of linked lists) but I can't get my "erase()" function to work (it would clean the entire list and delete each node).  If you can take a look at this and point me in the right direction.

The Node Structure

```
struct Node
{
    string m_str;
    Node *m_pNext;
    Node(void) {m_pNext = NULL;}
};
    Node *m_pHead;
```

The erase function

```
Void LLString::erase (void){
if (!m_pHead)
{
    return;
}

Node *temp = m_pHead;

while (temp)
{
    temp = m_pHead;      // The error allways shoes up around her
    if (temp->m_pNext)   // It has moved around a little as I have tried
    {                    // different things.  It is an unhanded exception
        m_pHead = temp->m_pNext;
    }
    temp->m_pNext = NULL;
    delete temp;
    }
}
```

My add function

```
void LLString::add (string str)
{
Node *nNode = new Node;
nNode -> m_str = str;
nNode ->m_pNext = m_pHead;
m_pHead = nNode;
}
```

And the only other function I am currently using with the program is this function sending everything to a file. (used right before the erase function)

```
void LLString::toFile (void)
{
ofstream fout;
fout.open ("stringData.txt",ios::app);

Node* temp = m_pHead;
while (temp)
{
    fout << temp->m_str << endl;
    temp = temp->m_pNext;
}
fout.close();
}
```

Again if you have any idea why that delete isn't working please point it out to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple recursive function:

```
void erase(Node *n)
{
  if (n)
  {
    erase(n->m_pNext);
    delete(n);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to have an `else` there instead of just a statement outside of the `if`? As it stands the only think you will call `delete` for will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

problem is that you never let **m_pHead** null so your **temp** is also don't get null and while loop never terminate and cause double deletion.

I modified your code, which seems to work fine.

```
    void erase (){
    if (!m_pHead)
    {
        return;
    }

    Node *temp = m_pHead;
    while (temp)
    {
        m_pHead = temp->m_pNext;
        delete temp;
        temp = m_pHead;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I originally had as my code but it gives the following error  
---Unhandled exception at 0x010f9531 in hw5_hash.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfdfdfe1d. ---
It starts to compile but stops at the line 
-- m_pHead = temp->m_pNext; --
Do you know what would cause that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Node *m_pHead = NULL;
```

The erase function:

```
Void LLString::erase (void)
{
if (m_pHead==NULL)
{
    return;
}

Node *temp = m_pHead;

while (temp->m_pnext!=NULL)
{
   m_pHead = temp->m_pNext;
   delete temp;
   temp = m_pHead;
}
delete temp;
m_pHead = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Still the same error at - while (temp-> m_pNext != NULL) - It doesn't let me check for temp-> m_pNext.  I can't figure out why though.

Comment: I dont think there is any error in the code it must be something other than the code. what compiler are you using?

Comment: try implementing it as a class instead of struct. its not a solution but just a suggetion to try different things.

Comment: or write a delete function that would delete one node and see if it works, and then try to call it repeatedly to erase all your nodes.

Comment: On on a windows pc using visual studio 2010 ultimate.  I wondered the same thing. I tried repairing the program and doing updates and everything but no luck.  I guess this is something that I will have to work out myself.  Thanks again everyone for helping me out.